# Prisma error on create method - Argument name and Argument location is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am creating the place then I keep getting the Prisma error yet I am providing all the required data. Every time I am creating the place I get this error yet I provided all the required data. I'm not getting where I could have possibly made the error I checked and checked again my code.

```
Invalid `this.prisma.place.create()` invocation in
C:\Users\charm\tourism-portal\src\place\place.service.ts:12:52

   9 constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}
  10
  11 async createTouristicPlace(adminId: number, dto: CreatePlaceDto) {
→ 12   const touristicPlace = await this.prisma.place.create({
         data: {
           admin: {
             connect: {
               id: 35
             }
           },
       +   name: String,
       +   location: String,
       ?   createdAt?: DateTime,
       ?   updatedAt?: DateTime
         }
       })

Argument name for data.name is missing.
Argument location for data.location is missing.
```

here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreatePlaceDto, EditPlaceDto } from './dto';
import { PrismaService } from '../prisma/prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class TouristicPlaceService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async createTouristicPlace(adminId: number, dto: CreatePlaceDto) {
    const touristicPlace = await this.prisma.place.create({
      data: {
        admin: {
          connect: { id: adminId },
        },
        ...dto,
      },
    });
    console.log(dto);
    return console.log(touristicPlace);
  }
```

and here is my dto

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreatePlaceDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  location: string;
}
```

and my db model

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Admin {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  adminID   String  @unique
  email     String  @unique
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  hash      String
  Places    Place[]

  @@map("admins")
}

model Place {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  name     String
  location String

  adminId Int
  admin   Admin @relation(fields: [adminId], references: [id])

  @@map("places")
}
```

I am trying to create a place endpoint but I kept getting a Prisma error which I'm not really getting I am new to Prisma and NestJs.

Comment: So are they strings and not empty? Perhaps test that with a console.log

Comment: @mplungjan yes they are strings and not empty I tried but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Does `console.log(...dto)` give you the expected values?

Comment: I think the property name may not be present in the object dto, check that object dto using the console.log(dto)

Comment: I got where I made the error I wasn't passing the dto in the body in my controller.

Comment: @D12 question is closed? Or error is exist?

Comment: Log the object dto (console.log(dto)), Because the name and the location property might have undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Prisma` to create or update records with relations, it's essential to ensure the data structure matches what `Prisma` expects. Misalignment can result in unexpected behaviors or errors.

In your situation, it's crucial to inspect the `dto` (Data Transfer Object) construction. If asynchronous operations are used to generate or modify the `dto`, it might not be ready or correctly structured by the time it's used in the `Prisma` `create` method.

For troubleshooting, I recommend building your data object step-by-step rather than relying solely on the spread operator with dto (please check this `create` function without use values from `dto` at first to check if it work correct):

```
const touristicPlace = await this.prisma.place.create({
  data: {
    admin: {
      connect: { id: adminId },
    },
    name: "value",
    location: "value",
    // ... add other fields manually here
  },
});
```

Instead of:

```
const touristicPlace = await this.prisma.place.create({
  data: {
    admin: {
      connect: { id: adminId },
    },
    ...dto,
  },
});
```

This approach lets you see each field clearly and can help identify any anomalies or missing values in the dto. Once you're confident about the dto's structure and contents, you can then reintegrate it with the spread operator.